# IFV and AA vehicle locations on console maps

Tags: battlefield-3

Would someone be able to list which console maps have IFVs (LAV-alike) and AA (Tunguska-alike) vehicles and where they are located (and in which modes)?

I am trying to level up those two but they are pretty hard to find comparing to tanks. Don't know any Tunguska locations on conquest for example.

Comment: Generally, any map that has airplanes *and* helicopters is going to have an AA vehicle.

Comment: Not the case;  this answer is vastly dependent on the platform.

Answer (score 5):

On consoles prior to the Back to Karkand map pack mobile AA was only available on the Noshahr Canals Rush map for the defending team.

[image: Rush Zone 1 - Dry Dock]

At the start of the round it is located in what I think is called the train yard. Look just to the right of the orange square marking the RU deployment.

A number of the other maps have stationary AA guns but I don't think these count towards leveling up.

In the Back to Karkand map pack Wake Island definitely has them in Rush for the defending team. Again, they are usually towards the back of the base. The first one is by the bridge ([Roughly marked with Google Maps](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=19.304623,166.632321&hl=en&ll=19.304359,166.631398&spn=0.017801,0.033023&t=h&z=16&vpsrc=6)).

According to the IGN BF3 Wiki the [9K22 TUNGUSKA-M](http://au.ign.com/wikis/battlefield-3/9K22_TUNGUSKA-M) and [LAV-AD](http://au.ign.com/wikis/battlefield-3/LAV-AD) don't appear on any other maps on the consoles.

Comment: This is by no means a complete answer but it can serve as a starting point or at least give you some info up front.

Comment: I remember being torn apart frequently by a Tunguska on Operation Firestorm.

Comment: They do have them in Wake Island on Conquest Mode, too.

Answer (score 2):

The AA vehicles [9K22 Tunguska](http://bf3blog.com/battlefield-3-tunguska/) and its counter-alternative [LAV-AD](http://bf3blog.com/battlefield-3-lav-ad/) both appear on the following maps **on PC**.

- Caspian Border
- Operation Firestorm
- Kharg Island

They also appear on the Back to Karkand Maps: I certainly saw one on the Wake Island.

The IFVs [BMP-2](http://bf3blog.com/battlefield-3-bmp-2/) (Russian version) and [LAV-25](http://bf3blog.com/battlefield-3-lav-25/) (US version) appear on the following maps, one for each side.

- Noshahr Canals
- Tehran Highway
- Grand Bazaar

Comment: Wake Island is probably the best to level up the AA on, as the opposition generally operate a lot of aircraft...

Answer (score 0):

In consoles you can also access Tunguska on Wake Island Conquest as can be seen in this video:

Edit: There is no Conquest Wake Island, but Conquest Assault.